# What does "if known" refer to at the end of a sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modifiers

What does the "if known" refer to in this sentence? :

> The Notice to Suspend shall specify the reason for suspension, which part of the Works shall be suspended, the effective date of the suspension and the expected date for resumption of the Works, **if known**.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, the sentence is ambiguous; the "if known" may be read as modifying either the whole sequence of coordinated direct objects (from "the reason" through "resumption of the Works") or only the last one ("the expected date for resumption of the Works"). In practice, however, only the latter reading really makes sense; there's no reason that a notice might be issued without a known reason, scope, or start-date — and the latter two are rather essential for the notice to have any meaning — but it's quite possible that there's no expected end-date yet at the time when the notice is issued.